# refresh a View page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

In my page, I show an order with its products and price for each product in this 
order, the user is able to change the price of each product.

The function for changing the price is working well but my problem is that the user must refresh the page to see the price is updated.

Is there any way to refresh the view and at the same action that update the price.

function for updating price:

```
public ActionResult UPPDATEPrise(int VaraId, int pris, int kundId)
{
    int _Orderid = GetLastOrderId();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ENTERPRISE-PC;Initial Catalog=Fakturor;Integrated Security=True");
    String command = "UPDATE [Fakturor].[dbo].[Varor]  SET pris="+pris+" WHERE [id]="+VaraId+"";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command,conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return RedirectToAction("UdateOrderDetails", new { kundId = kundId, OrderId = _Orderid });     
}
```

Here my action that returns to the view:

```
public ActionResult UdateOrderDetails(int kundId, int OrderId)
{
    //Orders procuts
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var t1 = (from p in db.Varors
                  join
                  op in db.OrderVarors on p.id equals op.IdVara
                  where op.IdOrder == OrderId  
                  select p).ToList();

    ViewBag.OrderItems = t1;
    //customer details
    ViewBag.id= kundId;

    //Order id
    ViewBag.OrderId = OrderId;
    // All products 
    ViewBag.varor=HamtarVaror();

    return View("Create");
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that updates a price for a product.

Comment: edited, here my price updating function

Comment: As a side note, you should probably look at using [ViewModels](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) instead of the ViewBag.  You should definitely look at using [query parameters](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) regardless of the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the browser is caching the page on direct.  Not sure this will work but as an example of how to prevent caching (not the best implementation, just an example):

Set a flag that something was updated in tempdata.

```
public ActionResult UPPDATEPrise(int VaraId, int pris, int kundId)
{
  // ALL YOUR CURRENT CODE....

  TempData["IsCacheDisabled"] = true;

  return RedirectToAction("UdateOrderDetails", 
    new { kundId = kundId, OrderId = _Orderid });
}
```

Check for it and update cache values:

```
public ActionResult UdateOrderDetails(int kundId, int OrderId)
{
  // ALL YOUR CURRENT CODE....

  if (TempData["IsCacheDisabled"] != null
      && (bool)TempData["IsCacheDisabled"])
  {
    var cache = HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    cache.SetNoStore();
  }

  return View("Create");
}
```

Comment: 1- name 'filterContext' does not exist in the current context 
2- Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'object'

Comment: Updated per your comments.

Comment: No, that is not the answer, i still need to refresh the page manualy to se the changes

Comment: Sounds like a Browser Caching problem.

Comment: have tried chrome and explorer, the problem is still the same